# How do I create CentOS 7 Persistent Policy-Based-Routing Rules?

Tags: centos, networking

I have 2 network interfaces on my "CentOS 7 Minimal" box.
I need to setup policy based routing, so that if a request comes in on one interface, the reply gets sent out the same interface.
Doing this with iproute2 in a non-persistent way is not terribly difficult:

```
echo '200 isp2' >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via 1.1.1.1 table isp2
ip rule add from 192.168.1.50 table isp2
```

Where 1.1.1.1 is my router, and 192.168.1.50 is my linux's IP.
The problem is making this persistent.

From what I've read, there's no iproute2 persistence file - the way to make things persistent is to add them to your network startup scripts.

Normally, RedHat recommends creating the file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ethX to add routes, but this does not appear to be able to add routes to a secondary routing table.

The solution seems to be to add the "ip route" and "ip rule" lines from above to /etc/sysconfig/network instead. This almost works, except for one thing: Every time the network is restarted, it keeps adding duplicate "ip rule" rules, dozens at a time.

After restarting my network 2 or 3 times with "systemctl restart network", my `ip rule` output looks like this:

```
0: from all lookup local
32670: from 192.168.1.50 lookup isp2
32671: from 192.168.1.50 lookup isp2
...
32764: from 192.168.1.50 lookup isp2
32765: from 192.168.1.50 lookup isp2
32766: from all lookup main
32767: from all lookup default
```

What is the proper way to add persistent policy-based-routing rules on CentOS 7?

PS. The `ip route list table isp2` command shows a single entry, as expected, so that's not a problem.

Edit: According to the RedHat 7 manual:

> in Red Hat Enterprise Linux the use of the global /etc/sysconfig/network file is deprecated

This is in favour of interface-specific config files, which don't appear to be able to add routes to a different routing table, and can't add `ip rule` rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing NetworkManager-config-routing-rules, and enabling NetworkManager-dispatcher seems to have fixed it:

```
$ sudo yum install NetworkManager-config-routing-rules
$ sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
$ sudo systemctl start NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
```

Now I can have this in my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ethX:

```
default via 1.1.1.1 table isp2
```

And this in my /etc/sysconfig/network/scripts/rule-ethX:

```
from 192.168.1.50 table isp2
```

And a definition for isp2 in my /etc/iproute2/rt_tables:

```
200 isp2
```

Restarting the network service no longer creates duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

Given the reading of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-routes` the lines from `route-(interface)` are parsed as is into `ip route add`, therefore to add the routes in a certain table, just add `table XXX` to the line. However, you might need to resort to table number instead of name from `rt_tables` to successfully add the route.

With rules, you can use `rule-(interface)` file, and actually current version of `ifup-routes` and `ifdown-routes` process these files like route files. This might not be the case with your set of scripts, to verify run `grep rule /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-routes`.

Your primary problem actually arises from sourcing of `/etc/sysconfig/network` by each of ifup and ifdown scripts, therefore each command in that file is executed once per up/down of every interface. This in turn makes your system to add 2*interfaces (including `lo`) additions of IP rule per network restart.

PS: I have uninstalled CentOS network manager, so everything is done with ifup/ifdown scripts, and I have tested all this before posting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Restarting the network service no longer creates duplicate entries.

That is not true unfortunately. It is if you just keep restarting the network service without any modifications, but if you edit an already existing rule, for example you change this:

```
from 10.1.2.0/23 table 300
```

to this:

```
from 10.1.2.0/24 table 300
```

and then you restart the network service, look what happens:

```
ip rule list table 300
32763:  from 10.1.2.0/23 lookup 300
32764:  from 10.1.2.0/24 lookup 300
```

Duplicate rules, as the 32763:  from 10.1.2.0/23 lookup 300 should have been deleted.

Further more: if you comment, or completely delete all the rules from a "rule-ifname" file, and restart the network service, all previous rules are still going to be there.

So no, this is not a solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/424674)